# Godot, Is it possible to detect collision between KinematicBody2D and Area2D, from the KinematicBody2D?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, godot

In my project, the Projectiles are `KinematicBody2D` nodes but the objects in the scenario are simple `AreaD` nodes.

I am trying to detect, inside the Projectile script, when the Projectile is colliding with any of the other `Area2D` in the scenario.

Using [KinematicBody2D.move_and_collide()](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-move-and-collide) looks like it is only colliding with nodes of type [PhysicsBody2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsbody2d.html#class-physicsbody2d).

I know that from `Area2D` we can detect when a Body is entering. But I want to detect the collision from the `KinematicBody2D` where is where my *hit* logic is set.

Is it possible to detect collision between `KinematicBody2D` and `Area2D`, from the `KinematicBody2D`?

(Maybe it is just not possible and I have to transform all my *collisionable* nodes to `PhysicsBody2D` instead of `Area2D`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect collision between KinematicBody2D and Area2D, from the KinematicBody2D?

No.

---

The closest to what you ask is to query which areas are overlapping using `Physics2DDirectSpaceState`:

```
var world:World2D = get_world_2d()
var space_state:Physics2DDirectSpaceState = world.direct_space_state
var query := Physics2DShapeQueryParameters.new()
query.collide_with_areas = true
query.collide_with_bodies = false
query.transform = $Collider.global_transform
query.set_shape($Collider.shape)
var collisions:Array = space_state.intersect_shape(query)
for collision in collisions:
    var area:Area2D = collision["collider"]
    print(body)
```

---

However, your `Area2D` can detect the `KinematicBody2D` and tell it about it. Connect the body entered signal to the `Area2D` itself, and have code like this:

```
func _on_area2d_body_entered(body):
    if body.has_method("collided"):
        body.call("collided", self)
```

And in the bullet you define method to be called by that:

```
func collided(area):
     # whatever you need to do
    pass
```

---

I would have done your design the other way around. The objects in the world would be `StaticBody` (for example) and the projectiles are `Area2D`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this in my projects is to create an auto-load script that defines signals that the area can emit and the kinematic bodies can connect to. The area passes the entered body through the signal so that all instances of the body that connect to this signal are able to determine which of them entered the body.

autload script:

```
extends Node

signal area_entered(area_node, kinematic_body_node)
```

area script:

```
func on_body_entered(body):
    AutoLoadScript.emit_signal("area_entered", self, body)
```

kinematic body script:

```
func _ready():
    AutoLoadScript.connect("area_entered", self, "_hit")

func _hit(area_node, kinematic_body_node):
     if kinematic_body_node == self:
         hit logic...
```

I have found this approach to be a little easier to work with than calling functions directly on the kinematic body from the area. This decouples the two scenes so that the area doesn't need to know anything about the entered body's "hit" logic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems you want to know when two objects touch from the KinematicBody2D and the Area2D. Well, if you have the Area2D pick up the collision, then it can raise a signal to the KinematicBody2D (https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html) I think this should work, but I don't know the specifics of your project, so this might not work.